# Where does Elaticsearch take the elasticsearch-keystore password from?

Tags: security, elasticsearch, password-protection

I've been reading the little [documentation Elastic provides](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/elasticsearch-keystore.html), but it is just about how to operate it. And I don't really understand the fundamentals of it.

1. You initialise the keystore with a password: `bin/elasticsearch-keystore passwd`
2. You add a key-value to it `bin/elasticsearch-keystore add mySecret` (prompts for secret)
3. You refer to the key inside elasticsearch.yml i.e. `${mySecret}`
4. Start Elasticsearch, and the value is magically extracted and replaced from the keystore.

My doubt is: how does Elasticsearch get the password to decrypt the keystore and use the values in the configuration file? Or is the keystore password stored somewhere?

If yes, where? In this case I don't see the benefit of using keystore at all?

Comment: Am i mistaken in my reading that those documents say `When the keystore is password-protected, you must supply the password each time Elasticsearch starts.`?

Comment: I missed that part (or I read it, but my brain refused to believe it). So all the keystore does is some kind of obfuscation? Isn't this equivalent to hard coding a symmetric encryption/decryption key in ES code?

Comment: Values in the keystore are definitely encrypted, as far as I am aware, i think its just an extra layer of protection for sensitive values!

Comment: But if they are encrypted (and evidently decrypted by Elasticsearch runtime)... Where is the decryption key saved? And how to protect that?

Comment: Judging by the KeyStoreWrapper, it looks like your password is used as the key: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/a92a647b9f17d1bddf5c707490a19482c273eda3/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/settings/KeyStoreWrapper.java#L299

Comment: Yeah if you set one. Looks like it's optional. The part that confuses me is when your keystore password is not set?

Comment: "When the keystore is password-protected, you must supply the password each time Elasticsearch starts." I could not figure out yet how to provide the password. Any hint?

Comment: Haven't tested this, but it looks like you can use the KEYSTORE_PASSWORD environment variable.  See https://discuss.elastic.co/t/keystore-password-file/339627 and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-keystore-bind-mount

Answer (score 2):

Currently I am using elasticsearch v7.10. Its systemd service runs `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint` as its `ExecStart`. By looking at it, you can see that it is trying to read keystore password from a file specified by environment variable `ES_KEYSTORE_PASSPHRASE_FILE`.

You can create a file, containing your passphrase, add an `Environment` directive in your service file and assign `ES_KEYSTORE_PASSPHRASE_FILE` to path of your file.

```
touch /var/elasticpassword
echo MY_STRONG_PASSWORD > /var/elasticpassword
vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service
```

in `[service]` section add the following line:

```
Environment=/var/elasticpassword
```

Reload systemctl and restart the service

```
systemctl daemon-reload
service elasticsearch restart
```

Answer (score 1):

@sscarduzio
place your password in ansible yml file, protect the yml file with ansible-vault, this way you only have to remember and type only the vault password for all the keystores and sensitive passwords
with some further tricks depensing on your setup you can automate further and supply vault password with automation